# WHERE parameter equals ANY column (Entity attribute) value

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I need to write a generic NamedQuery; such as, find me all the objects where any of the attributes matches the given parameter.

select mo from MyObject mo where mo.ANYAttribute = someParameter

I could not figure out the expression for "where mo.ANYAttribute". The sort of wildcard such as " + or * or ANY or .)... Something that will save me from writing query where I have to write manually to check for each attribute such as:

where mo.attribute1= :someParameteror or mo.attribute2 = :someParameter

I am using JPA 2.0.

Is it possible this way or I have to change my approach?

Many Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list all attributes of an entity, there is no such thing as ANYAttribute in JPA:

```
  where mo.attr1=:someParamter or mo.attr2=:someParameter etc.
```

Comment: True, could have done this way; but I am looking for something like a wildcard such as ANY/*

Comment: Oops :) Anything that I can use to hint the Entity Manager to match All the Entity's fields? I am trying to do this, as I might choose the query as a generic search for the logs that we keep in our database.

Comment: No. Only explicit enumerating of all fields. It's like SQL - it doesn't have wildcards for field names.

Comment: That sums it up then. Thank you for your time Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of [@NamedQuery](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/NamedQuery) usage with parameters:

Annotate your entity with:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findEntityById",
query = "SELECT entity FROM Entity entity WHERE entity.id = :inputId")
```

Entity manager usage:

```
Query namedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findEntityById");
namedQuery.setParameter("inputId", 1);
```

[A very good tutorial on NamedQueries.](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named)

Comment: Thanks JMelnik, I looked at it. I edited my question. I am do a bit of JPA, but I am trying to find a generic query that will match all the attributes without me doing the hardcode for all the matches.